# Compound assignment in C++

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, compound-assignment

I would like to know the execution flow of compound assignments in C++. I came across a [CodeChef question](https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA05/submit/BINXOR), where I am calculating NCR mod p values and adding them together to get the final answer:

```cpp
// correct
for(int i=min1; i<=max1; i+=2){
     ans = (ans+ncr_mod_p(n,i))%mod;
}
```

```cpp
// incorrect
for(int i=min1; i<=max1; i+=2){
     ans+=ncr_mod_p(n,i)%mod;
}
```

This is happening because of integer overflow.

So, what is the execution sequence of compound assignment?

Let's say, if we have an equation `a+=b%c` then what would be the execution sequence:

```cpp
a = (a+b)%c
// OR
a = a+(b)%c;
```

Comment: Start from the innermost parentheses. In case of equally parenthesised operations, see the order of precedence.

Comment: Just google _cppreference operator precedence_? Compound assignment isn't special there.

Comment: I was not very confident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement

```
ans+=ncr_mod_p(n,i)%mod;
```

is equivalent to the statement

```
ans = ans + ( ncr_mod_p(n,i)%mod );
```

As you can see it differs from the statement

```
ans = (ans+ncr_mod_p(n,i))%mod;
```

From the C++ 14 Standard (5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 7 **The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent
> to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once.** In += and
> -=, E1 shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly
> cv-qualified completely-defined object type. In all other cases, E1
> shall have arithmetic type.

Answer (score 6):

The compound assignment operators are in the [*second lowest* precedence group](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of all in C++ (taking priority over only the comma operator). Thus, your `a += b % c` case would be equivalent to `a += ( b % c )`, or `a = a + ( b % c )`.

This explains why your two code snippets are different. The second:

```cpp
    ans+=ncr_mod_p(n,i)%mod;
```

is equivalent to:

```cpp
    ans = ans + ( ncr_mod_p(n,i) % mod );
```

Which is clearly different from the first (correct) expression:

```cpp
    ans = ( ans + ncr_mod_p(n,i) ) % mod;
```